# Rules - how to check if user has role(s)

Tags: drupal-8

In the module Rules, I try to check if a user has role(s).

So, I add a condition `"User has role(s)"`. In the field `"Data selector"` (in data selection mode), I add `node.uid.entity`, in the field `roles`, I add my 
roles `("seller, "buyer")`, in the field `match roles`, I add `"OR"`. 
I click on save.
I got this error:
`"Expected a entity:user data type for context User but got a entity_reference data type instead."`

I don't understand what to put in the field `"Data selector".`

[image]